# Auto configuring IIS websites / app pools using PowerShell or other scripts

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, iis-8, iis-8.5, iis-modules

We have a need in our project to automate the process of creating AppPools and Websites in IIS . We would like to write some batch script to get this done. From my research I found that PowerShell has commands that can be used. However when I tried to run IIS module commands in PowerShell on Windows Server 2012 , it does not recognize the commands. Is it correct that this feature was only available for Windows 7 / IIS 7 ? Is it also available now on Windows 2012 R2 / IIS 8. If so where can I find proper documentation and help ?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is of course available in Windows 8/8.1 and Windows Server 2012/2012 R2.

You probably forgot to run `Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration` before executing other IIS cmdlets.

You can find the full documentation on the [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899(v=wps.620).aspx).

If you run Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 (i.e. you have Windows PowerShell 4.0) you can also use the new [PowerShell Desired State Configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249912.aspx) feature with the [xWebAdministration Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be) to create WebAppPools and Websites.

Comment: Chris , thanx. Running the above cmmand gives me the error:  PS C:\Users\Dev1> Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'WebAdministration' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WebAdministration:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Comment: The IIS role needs to be installed for the WebAdministration PowerShell module to be available. You can quickly install it with the `Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server` command.